# Soccer contest rule puzzled me

Tags: self-study, data-visualization

I have a little knowledge about soccer contest rule, there is a question I cannot understand.

The dotplot below shows the numbers of goals scored by 20 teams playing in a city's high school soccer games on a particular day.

Please use the following code to create the dotplot.

```
A <- c(0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,7,10)  
stripchart(A, method = "stack", offset = .5, at = .15, pch = 19,xaxt="n")  
axis(1, at = 0:9, labels = 0:9)
```

1. One superstar scored six goals, but his team still lost, what are all possible final scores for that game? Explain.
2. Is it possible that all the teams scoring exactly two goals won their games? Explain.

Answers:

1. If the player scored six goals, his/her team must have scored either 7 or 10, but they lost, so they scored 7, and the only possible final score is that they lost by a score of 10 to 7.
2. No, there were six teams that scored exactly two-goals, but there were only five teams that scored less than two goals, so not all the two-goal teams could have won.

I read the answer over and over, but I still cannot understand.

Comment: Other than the (gratuitous) use of R, I'm not sure there's a statistical question here--they're just simple logic puzzles and I'm not sure it's possible to do much better than the answers you provided.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user1142618. I don't quite follow your question. Which of the 2 question-answer pairs are you having difficulty with? Are you having trouble with the rules for soccer, or how to interpret a dotplot, or how the numbers add up?

Comment: There is a way in which the question as to do with combinations of valid outcomes.  Whether that is in-scope or not is another issue.

Comment: I agree with @Russell (if I interpret his comment correctly): to the extent that answering this question requires reasoning about data, it can be construed as on topic.  The text of this question, though, could be appreciably improved by applying the recommendations in our [faq] for posting good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is at best only a restating of the answers the question asker posted, but I hope a mild re-phrasing will help them.

Know that soccer scoring is simple.  There is one point per goal.  The team with the most points at the end of the game wins.  A tie is not the same as a win.

Given that one player scored 6 goals, but his team still lost the only valid combinations are ones where:

$Team_{Superstar} \geq 6$ AND $Team_{Superstar} < Team_{Other}$

The first condition means that only these scores are valid for $Team_{Superstar}$

```
A[A >= 6]
```

I.e.:  7 and 10

If $Team_{Superstar} == 7$, then to meet the second condition the only possible value for $Team_{Other}$ is

```
A[A >= 7]
```

I.e. 10.

If $Team_{Superstar} == 10$, then there is no possible value to meet the second condition.

```
A[A > 10]
```

Therefore, the final score was 7 to 10.

For the second part, we can see that there are six teams that scored two points.  Given that there are only five teams that scored less than 2 points, it is not possible for all of the teams that scored two points to be winners of their game (because at the very least at least one of the 2 point teams must be paired up with another 2 point team or a 3, 4, or 5 point team).